# Why grep is not recursing

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a directory named `0-golang` with subfolders where some `.go` files have got "closer" text. But `grep` command with `-r` or `-R` or `-d recurse` are not finding these:

```
0-golang$ grep -r "closer" *.go 
0-golang$ grep -R "closer" *.go 
0-golang$ grep -d recurse "closer" *.go
```

Above command produce no output. But following command using `find`, `xargs` and `grep` shows those strings:

```
0-golang$ find | grep go$ | xargs -I {} grep closer {}
        "github.com/xlab/closer"
                closer.Fatalln(err)
                closer.Fatalln(err)
                closer.Fatalln("opengl: init failed:", err)
        closer.Bind(func() {
```

Why the `bash grep` commands are not finding recursively? I have to incorporate this function in a bash script file.

Comment: Well, `*.go` will expand only to the `.go` files, not to directories. So `grep` has nothing to recurse to. You can use `globstar`: `grep closer **/*.go`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The troublemaker is the `*.go` glob at the end of the command line. The shell expands `*.go` to the list of `.go` files in the current directory and passes the updated command line to `grep`. The request to search recursively does not make any sense for `grep` in this case and it ignores it.

To solve the problem you have to tell `grep` to search recursively (`-r`) in the current directory (`.`) and check only the files that match the `*.go` pattern (`--include`).

The complete command line is:

```
grep -r --include="*.go" "closer" .
```

The quotes around the `*.go` patterns are required to prevent the shell to expand the pattern. Otherwise you'll end up in a situation similar as before. The quotes around `closer` are needed only if the text to search (`closed` in this case) contains spaces or characters that are special to the shell.

Answer (score 4):

The `-r` will recurse any directories given as arguments, but `*.go` doesn't cover directories, just files in the current directory (unless you have funny directory names).

GNU `grep` lets you control the patterns of files to examine while recursing with `--include` but the file name argument should simply be `.` to examine the current directory (and, with `-r`, its subdirectories).

Your `find` attempt can be simplified and improved (better precision; more correct);

```
find . -type f -name '*.go' -exec grep 'closer' /dev/null {} +
```

The quotes prevent the shell from expanding `*.go` here. Adding `/dev/null` as an argument to `grep` is a common hack to make sure `grep` always receives more than one file name (which implicitly enables `-H` and some other good defaults).

Comment: Good answer. I would use `grep -H moo {} \;` if you want to use `find`. (I assume you are using `find` because `grep -r` is a GNU extension)

Comment: @hek2mgl The `+` is similar to `\;` but allows `find` to minimize the number of external processes.

Comment: What I want to say is, if you assume a non-posix GNU environment with a version of `find` that supports `+`, then you can probably just use `grep -r`. I suggested to use `grep -H moo {} \;` for posix compatibility but I just realized that `grep -H` is not posix. Sorry, nvm my comment then.

Comment: the /dev/null hack is nice! :)